# Bug when trying to edit a post in a review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, first-post-review

There appears to be a bug in the *review first post* queue:

1. A post needs editing. I click on *edit*
2. No error message appear, but the windows scrolls to the top

Looking at the source code, the *edit* link has the following attribute: `data-error-message="Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed."`, which clearly explains why I don't get redirected to the edit page.

[drive link to a video of the bug](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a8PSpPRBjnN0-g-6uS2gD5cX8T1-WR4b/view)

I believe however that this error message is supposed to be displayed normally somehow - I mean, I know we're developers, but hiding error messages in HTML element attributes seems kind of over the top, am I right?

Comment: Faced the same issue

Comment: This also happens when you run out of suggested edits as well: no error, the `edit` button just doesn't work.

Comment: And not just first posts, everything with an `edit` button on the review pages. (as far as I can tell)

Comment: @EthanK not for me - error shows up when clicking edit on post page, bug doesn't shows up when clickin edit on review post page

Comment: @NinoFiliu Okay, I might be wrong. I really haven't seen the bug that much -- only once. So I could be (and probably am) wrong.